# How do I read data from a TCP socket and display it in a three js in an html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, three.js

I have a TCP server (using embedded linux) which is sending raw binary data to a IP address and port. On the client side (PC), I would like to read this data and give it to three js in my browser javascript and display it using WebGL. I understand that java script does not allow reading raw TCP sockets. I can use node js (again from the same PC) to read the TCP socket data. I can read the raw TCP socket data using node.js and then I need to pass that data to my java script for WebGL rendering.

How do I pass the data from node js to browser java script? Is there a simple example which I can refer to?

Does it make sense to read the raw TCP socket data in node.js and transfer it via http server setup in node.js and listen to the binary data in java script using socket.IO?

Is there any simpler way of reading raw TCP sockets in javascript or you think one of the above approaches is simpler and is the appropriate way?

Is setting up http server in embedded platform simpler enough and read binary data directly in javascript using http server requests using socket IO APIs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you straight up can't do this.

Comment: Any pointers on what should be the next step?

Comment: Absolutely no idea.